# Add element into an existing Map in Cloud Firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Through Flutter I want to add a Map element in Firestore.

Instead of fetching the whole map and replacing it with the added element is it possible to directly add a new key and value?

Example:

```
Map = { '2020-05-21' : true } -- Add --> Map = { '2020-05-21' : true, '2020-05-22': true }
```

This is how I tried to do this but without any success.

```
return collection.document('id').updateData({'map.$date' : true});
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this approach:

```
final ref = Firestore.instance.document('collection_id/document_id');

await ref.updateData({
  'field.key2': 'value2',
});
```

Since I am not having an idea about how your data looks like on server, I tested this one and it worked.

---

**Edit:**

```
// initial work
var ref = Firestore.instance.document('Employees/54G...Naf');
var initialData = {
  'date_1': '1',
};
await ref.setData({
  'busy_map': initialData,
});

// updated work
var updatedData = {
  'busy_map.date_2': '2',
};
await ref.updateData(updatedData);
```

Comment: this creates a new document field with a map.$date field name, but not a new field within the map

Comment: Hey thanks but how does this differ from my already posted code? My data looks like this: I have a document containing String fields plus a map that contains data (key: date, value: bool). I do not want to update the whole document or map. I just want to add a key and value into my map.

Comment: @Georgios Can you post your database structure?

Comment: Honestly no idea... I still think I typed the same thing. If I do understand why I will post it here.

Comment: @Georgios Alright, even I am willing to see, what the main cause was :)

Comment: I think this might have happened since in the beginning I did not have a map in Firestore. Still I am not 100% sure about this.

Comment: @Georgios Thats true. Update only works if there exists some data. So, that was the main reason.